# Fit an ellipsoid for given points in higher dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have few data points in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to fit a minimum volume  ellipsoid such that most of the points are contained inside it. Some outliers are allowed, however a large percentage of points should lie on the boundary or inside the ellipsoid. Can we compute such an ellipsoid ? Also how many points are needed to uniquely define such an ellipsoid.

Comment: I have an old answer somewhere, let me see if I can find it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895916/does-there-exist-a-unique-max-approximator-for-matrices check this out.

Comment: Let the points be vectors, subtract their means, then build outer products with themselves which you matrix power and then sum up into a tensor and lastly take same root as the power you took on the individual terms.

Comment: @mathreadler: Can you write it in mathematical terms. I don't understand matrix power and summation into tensor. Assume $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ be the matrix of $p$ data points. Can you please elaborate your steps over it.

Comment: I don't think I can describe in more mathematical terms but maybe a bit more detail programming friendly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Calculate the mean of all the data points, store it and then subtract it from each data point.
2. Create accumulating matrix $\bf A = 0$ (the zero matrix).
3. For each (now meanless) data point calculate it's outer product with itself. If I understand your notation correctly each column, multiply it with its own transpose to the left so you get a $n \times n$ matrix. Raise the matrix to some integer power $k$. Add the result ing matrix to $\bf A$
4. When all such matrices have been added calculate $\frac{1}{p}{\bf A}^{(1/k)}$. It's eigensystem will now describe the orientation of your ellipsoid and the mean vector you subtracted in 1 will be it's center coordinate.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I understood the steps of your approach. But what I don't understand is, why it will give us the required ellipsoid. Is there a proof or some journal reference to this approach ?

Comment: No. Just convince yourself.